# Why does Flickring occurs on Win Forms when more control are present on the UI

Tags: controls

If any one has got an explanation for why does flickering occur on a UI (for windows form) when it incorporates more sub controls (like, data grid's, images etc).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flickering is usually a problem that has to do with intensive graphics operations or custom draws. The best way to solve it is to make the flickering controls *double buffered*. Since you don't give us much to go by, that would be an obvious first choice. You could also manually *invalidate* controls triggered by certain events.

Here's an article that should get you started:

[Double Buffering Windows Forms](https://web.archive.org/web/20140811193726/http://bobpowell.net/doublebuffer.aspx)